# Selecting 'Delete' in UITableView cell swipe, but 'commit editingStyle' not called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe-gesture

I have the following -

```
    class BTTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

With these methods -

```
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print("editingStyle")
    }
```

When I left swipe on a cell, the 'Delete' option shows as expected -
[Delete action shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc13l.png)

If I -

1. tap on Delete, the method above with parameter 'commit editingStyle' is not called
2. swipe left all the way to the left side of the view instead of stopping when Delete appears, the method is called.

It seems to me this method would be called with both #1 & #2.

Can someone help me understand what I've done wrong?

EDIT - With DonMag's input, solved issue with:

```
     override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) {
            let isSwipeButton = String(describing: type(of: hitView)) ==  "UISwipeActionStandardButton"
            if hitView.isKind(of: BTTableCellContentView.self)  || isSwipeButton {
                return hitView
            }
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

Comment: If your class is a sub-class of `UITableView`, shouldn't those methods be `override`? ***Edit:*** Sorry, just realized it's not `UITableViewController`....

Comment: Hmmm... I just gave that a try, and `commit` is called for both full-swipe and partial-swipe-and-tap. Something else going on in your code? Maybe try a simple example?

Comment: I think you have an architectural problem as well. Your `UITableView` subclass shouldn't be the data provider of itself.

Comment: I’ll share a little more about my setup.  I’m attempting to make BTNavigationDropdownMenu support swipe to delete.  I’ve downloaded the project, made changes as shown in my question to BTTableView class, and point to the resulting build product in my Podfile.

Comment: @DaveLargent - for future reference, it's a good idea to provide ***all*** of the relevant information when you post your question.

Comment: @DonMag, yes, I will take that to heart for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears `commit` is not being called because that class is overriding `hitTest`:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) , hitView.isKind(of: BTTableCellContentView.self) {
        return hitView
    }
    return nil;
}
```

and returning `nil` because `hitView` is then the action button.

Simply removing it may/will cause issues (first one noticed is that the "drop down" doesn't close when tapping outside of it).

So you'll need to edit that function... might take a little work, but that's the place to start.

Comment: Had the the same issue and it led me to this answer. In my case I added a tap gesture recognizer to the entire view so that the user could tap anywhere outside the keyboard to dismiss it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to write:

```
self.delegate = self
self.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  I checked the source code of BTNavigationDropdownMenu and those two calls are present.